# Can someone in the process of conversion use the phone during shabbes?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, conversion-to-judaism

Until one reaches the mikveh, he/she is not a Jew just yet. Since they are obligated to break Shabbes in some way, can they use phones during the day? Should they refrain?

Comment: The person concerned should discuss this with the Rabbi who is guiding him in his conversion process. IMHO, the answer is likely to depend on the stage iin the process that the potential ger has reached.

Comment: There have been some people who will turn on a light before candle lighting time of Friday and after havdallah on Saturday in order to not "keep shabbos" for an entire day. That would be because the non-Jewish "day" is from midnight to midnight in our current society. However, this depends on the rav and the bais din monitoring the process.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. As you note, if they’re Jewish, Shabbos is obligatory, and if they’re not Jewish, Shabbos is forbidden. So what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MiYodeya! 
A person in a process of conversion still has the status of a gentile, and he is obligated to break shabbat. But the best thing is to keep it minimal. In my humble opinion, and how i learned from my rabbis as i am also in the process, breaking very small rabbinic melacha would suffice. When a person keeps on doing something he gets used to it. If you keep on breaking big melachot, youll get use to it and have it difficult to stop doing it when you are fully obligated to guard the shabbat. But if its a small thing that you're breaking, you will be able to leave it easily. Mobile phones are very addictive stuffs, and youll have a really hard time getting over it once you fully convert.

Comment: I've heard from converts that they were asked to bring their keys in their pockets during Shabbat (in a city without eiruv), but try to do the rest. Obviously it depends on the rabbi...

Comment: Yup the best thing to keep it minimal

Comment: There have been some people who will turn on a light before candle lighting time of Friday and after havdallah on Saturday in order to not "keep shabbos" for an entire day. That would be because the non-Jewish "day" is from midnight to midnight in our current society. However, this depends on the rav and the bais din monitoring the process.